# Sending a file from a Rails API to another Rails API, attaching to an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do this is.

I have one Rails API with ActiveStorage enabled, sending pdf files to an S3 bucket.  I have another Rails API with is an Email Microservice.

I want to send a request to my Email Microservice, from my main Rails API, with the file attachment included in the request, and then attach that to my email.

The solution I've come across below seems to get this done, but only if the mailer is happening on the same API:-

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end

class PhotoMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "default@example.com"

  def new_photo_email
    photo = params[:product].photo
    attachments[photo.filename.to_s] = photo.download
    mail(to: "one@example.com", subject: "Nueva photo")
  end
end

class PhotoMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def new_photo_email
    PhotoMailer.with(product: Product.first).new_photo_email
  end
end
```

i.e. it used ActiveStorage's `download` method.

This doesn't work when I'm sending a file to another API.  What would be the best way to achieve this?  Can I perhaps send just the file URL and then use `File.read(url)` in my Email service?  Or is there a way to send a file over an HTTP request that my Email service can grab?

Comment: Does it have to be an attachment? If not you can add a link to the s3 file in the email

Comment: @JoelBlum - that's a possible workaround but yeah, it would be better to have as an attachment.

Comment: > This doesn't work when I'm sending a file to another API , Could u explain what doesn't work ? Is it not sending the attachment or are you unable to receive it?

Comment: You shouldn't send the entire file to your other service, upload it to a service like S3 and send the link to your email service and fetch it from the service there. Amazon and other cloud storage providers have spent a lot of time making uploading/downloading efficient so for most use cases its better to use some service that abstracts that problem.